# Can TestCafe open source run test cases written in TestCafe studio?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, testcase

I'm trying to figure out if there is compatibility between test cases written in TestCafé Studio and TestCafé open-source.

The major difference is that open source only has the command line interface, but I suppose that a test case created with visual aid in TestCafé Studio still has some underlying code that is executable as command line in the open source version?

There is some more info here:  https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2016/10/18/testcafe-now-available-in-free-open-source-amp-commercial-studio-versions.aspx  and here  https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#what-is-the-difference-between-testcafe-studio-and-open-source-testcafe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run TestCafe Studio tests (.testcafe files) using TestCafe CLI. For more information refer to [our CLI documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#file-pathglob-pattern)